# Should I emphasize the hyphen, here?

Tags: hyphenation, emphasis

I need to emphasize one part of a combined word containing a hyphen (*cis*-Golgi). What would be correct? Including or excluding the hyphen / minus in `\emph{}`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: This isn't really a question *about TeX* since both options are trivial to implement and the question is implementation-agnostic.  I would ask on some other site… perhaps Graphic Design?  I'm honestly not sure…

Comment: @SeanAllred I agree that it's off topic - but it's a nice question with a nice accepted answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker whoops—the review didn't show me that! I definitely agree with the accepted answer though, and whether it is on/off topic is only *part* of what makes good question for a give site :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantically, the emphasis should be on *cis* only. The *cis* is italicised because it's a latin abbreviation. You are using the hyphen to indicate a compound name, and the hyphen is not part of the latin word, so it should not be emphasised.